# Infix notation for VertexLabels in a Graph (reformulated from a closed topic)

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am reformulating this question as it was incomplete.

I want to label vertices in a graph with expressions in infix notation.

I copy my code below. First part converts a list of expressions to infix notation. This works fine. Second part uses the same code to produce vertex labels in a graph. However the vertex labels produced do not remain in infix (instead they convert back to prefix code).

I include the code below.

```
Map[# /. S -> (Infix[S[##]] &) &, {S[1, 2], S[2, S[3, 4]]}]
```

This code produces infix code fine, yielding {1 ~ S ~ 2, 2 ~ S (3 ~ S ~ 4)}

However the following code:

```
HasseGraph[g_] := Fold[SetProperty[{#1, #2}, {Map[# /. S -> (Infix[S[##]] &) &, 
   VertexLabels] ->  #2}] &, g, VertexList[g]] 
HasseGraph[Graph[{S[1, 2] -> S[2, S[3, 4]]}]]
```

produces a graph for which the vertex labels are: S(2,(3,4)) and S(2,S(3,4)). I need these to be in infix notation as for the above example. The conversion to infix has not been preserved. Can you advise on how to make sure that the vertex labels remain in infix form?

Comment: Related question: is it possible to simply display the infix without the ~ signs that clutter up matters?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do:

```
HasseGraph[g_] := 
 With[{vlist = VertexList[g]}, 
  Graph[g, VertexLabels -> 
    Thread[vlist -> Map[# /. S -> (Infix[S[##]] &) &, vlist]]]]
HasseGraph[Graph[{S[1, 2] -> S[2, S[3, 4]]}]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem. The vertex labels still appear in prefix form.

Comment: @Mike I edited answer.

Comment: Brilliant, that dit it. Thanks, Halmir!

Comment: Is it possible to display infix notations  without the ~ signs? So a ~ S ~ b would become aSb as one would expect in infix?

Comment: @Mike Infix[S[##], S] could be what you want.

Comment: That worked, thanks.

Comment: When I replace S by tensor product \\[CircleTimes] as in  Infix[\\[CircleTimes] [##],  \\[CircleTimes] ] I get an error for the second tensor occurrence.

Comment: Is there a way to display a tensor product using  Infix[S[##], S] ?

Comment: I posted this as a separate question as it could be of use to others.

Answer (score 1):

Again, you could just define a format for `S` instead. In this case, [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph) uses [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) for labels, so you would need to use something like:

```
MakeBoxes[s_S, form_] ^:= MakeBoxes[Infix[s], form]
```

Then:

```
Graph[{S[1,2] -> S[2,S[3,4]]}, VertexLabels->Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Will try this one out as well.